# How do I properly cite my own course project in my master's thesis?

Tags: citations, thesis

I am writing up my MSc thesis right now, and I am including some material that I developed as part of one of my course projects (done during the MSc as well).

How do I cite that? It technically wasn't published anywhere, just submitted to the professor for grading and I did a powerpoint presentation about it.

Comment: Catsunami, unpublished

Comment: Did you think through the part about how are you going to make your cited material *available* for the readers?

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac, it's being used in my thesis - as in, I'm including the same derivations and possibly figures. That's what this question is about.